# Multiple methods expand or collapse?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I select multiple methods or piece of code containing multiple methods, I can only expand/collapse the first method.

And if I place caret to multiple positions via `Shift` + `Alt` + `Button Click`, then I can only expand/collapse the one where are placed the caret the last.

Is there a way to expand/collapse multiple methods in IDEA?

Note: I am using a shortcut `Ctrl` + `+/-` to expand or collapse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> Collapse All

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> Expand All

Comment: Works a bit oddly but works. It collapses all the methods inside the parent, but the parent itself. So you have to expand the parent after collapsing all.